# How to apply Effect Strip in Video Sequence Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Can I apply and remove an Effect Strip, for instance the Speed Control?
I mean like the modifiers, when we **Apply** them we also remove the controls. I want to remove the strips in the Video Sequence Editor but let the changes.
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

The command I was looking for was **Make Meta Strip** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).